# How can I print a variable to stdout in Postscript

Tags: postscript

I can print a string to stdout like this:

```
(%stderr) (w) file dup (a_string\n) writestring closefile
```

but I don't seem to be able to do

```
(a_string)
(%stderr) (w) file dup pop writestring closefile
```

or something similar.

Any help, please?

Comment: Use == you might want to add flush as well == flush See p526 of the 3rd edition PLRM. For strings you can use print. NB you are printing to stderr there, not stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're writing to stderr. To write to stdout, use `(%stdout)` as the special device.

But, if you're writing to stdout, just use `=` or `print` (if you don't want a newline).

To actually use `writestring` and `closefile`, Put the file first, then `dup` it, *then* put the string on the stack.

```
(%stderr) (w) file dup  % f f
(string)                % f f s
writestring             % f
closefile               %
```

If the string is already on the stack, you can do a little juggling to get the pieces in the right order.

```
(string)                % s
(%stderr)(w)file        % s f
exch                    % f s
1 index                 % f s f
exch                    % f f s
writestring
closefile
```

`exch 1 index exch` could also be written `dup 3 2 roll`.

Also, it is never necessary to close stdin, stdout, or stderr. So you can just lose that part.

```
(%stderr)(w)file (string) writestring
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change your pop to exch:

```
(a_string)
(%stderr) (w) file dup exch writestring closefile
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `dup` just made two file objects on the stack. `exch` here doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out this bug. I should have used 1 index exch, as you pointed out below.